# How can I disable/dim the screen when I click the pause button?

Tags: opengl, android, cocos2d

I am working in an android game using cocos2d. I want to dim the background screen when I click the pause button.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you mean dim the screen? The definitions I found of deem don't seem to fit your question unless I'm completely wrong.

Comment: Maybe start drawing a rectangular over the surface that get's darker over time...

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this effect by using a specified pixel from a texture I was already using in this way:

```
  CCSprite *layer = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:TEX_INTERFACE.textureAtlas.texture rect:CGRectMake(87, 143, 1, 1)];
  CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
  layer.scaleX = size.width;
  layer.scaleY = size.height;
  layer.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
  layer.opacity = 0;
  [game addChild:layer z:100 tag:TAG_PAUSE_OVERLAY];
  id action = [CCEaseOut actionWithAction:[CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.1 key:@"opacity" from:0 to:220] rate:2];
  [layer runAction:action];
```

Mind: this is Cocos2D for Objective-C, not for Android but translating it is straightforward

Comment: I have added one sprite   to make the background color gray. But when i click resume button still the background is remain gray color. How can i  remove the sprite when i click resume button.

Comment: you have to remove the sprite you added with `[parent removeChildByTag:TAG_PAUSE_OVERLAY]`

Comment: Thanks Jack . Really u r great !Its very helpful to me . Thanks so much for your  help.please continue it in future...

Answer (score -1):

I would need a bit of code to give a more detailed answer, but you probably want to use [glClearColor](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml) when you "click the pause button".

Comment: glClearColor affects the entire framebuffer and doesn't do any blending.